# Unit testing for unicode support

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to convert to unicode and create some unit tests to ensure that unicode is working.

Here is my current code, which fails on the mb_detect_encoding() line, and which I'm also not sure whether it is a valid test of unicode support:

```
    function testMultiLingualEncodings(){
        // Create this string via a heredoc.
        $original = '
        A good day, World!
Schönen Tag, Welt!
Une bonne journée, tout le monde!
يوم جيد، العالم
좋은 일, 세계!
Một ngày tốt lành, thế giới!
こんにちは、世界！
'; // Contains international characters from utf-8
        $this->assertTrue(mb_detect_encoding($original, 'UTF-8', true) === true); // Fails regardless of whether strict is true or not.
        $returned = query_item("select :multi limit 10", array(':multi'=>$original)); // Select this exact string, parameterized, from the database
        //debug($returned, string_diff($returned, $original));
        $this->assertTrue((bool)$original); // test original isn't null.
        $this->assertTrue((bool)$returned); // Test returned string isn't null.
        $this->assertTrue($original === $returned); // Test original exactly matches returned string
    }
```

So mb_detect_encoding() says that the initial string above isn't UTF-8.  I'm also trying to pass that string into the database and get it out, and then compare with the original string.  I'm not sure whether that is a valid test of the database connection's encoding, however.

So in general, how can I create a unit test for utf-8 support, and is the method above something that can be modified to resolve that goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but that doesn't make sense. Your test file is encoded in one format. Whatever you put into the test string will be encoded in the same way as the file is. I wouldn't also rely on the mb_detect_encoding function. Let's take following string: "abcde". It can be ASCII or UTF-8. You can't judge because there is no special character. Encoding is a way how you intemperate a data.

//EDIT

To make your test work do `$this->assertTrue(mb_detect_encoding($original, 'UTF-8') === 'UTF-8')`

Comment: I can make sure that the file is encoded in utf-8, though. (it is)  So at that point, I know that the original file is utf-8.  I have also included characters in the string that are utf-8 only.  As such, your "abcde" example doesn't seem to apply, since there are characters that are certainly -not- ascii in the test string.

Regardless, I simply created that file, I'm not claiming that that is the best way to test for unicode support, but if that doesn't work, what -will-.

Comment: To make your test work do `$this->assertTrue(mb_detect_encoding($original, 'UTF-8') === 'UTF-8')`

Comment: @LukaszKujawa Can you move your comment to be an edit of your answer? The tick would make sense then :-)