# Testing special characters with PHP Unit

Tags: symfony, utf-8, character-encoding, phpunit

I am testing my controller from Symfony2 with PHPUnit and the class `WebTestCase`

```
return self::$client->request(
    'POST', '/withdraw',
    array("amount" => 130),
    array(),array());

$this->assertEquals(
    "You can withdraw up to £100.00.",
     $crawler->filter("#error-notification")->text());
```

But I get this error:

```
Expected: "You can withdraw up to £100.00."
Actual:   "You can withdraw up to Â£100.00."
```

The thing is that in the webpage and the source code it looks fine, so I am thinking that maybe PHPUnit is having some trouble to fetch the text as UTF8?

What am I missing?

Comment: Could it be that £ is actually converted with entities resulting in `&pound;` ? This actually looks more like a utf-8 failure to me. Did you check all the code is utf-8 encoded? did you send the request with correct accept-charset headers?

Comment: The HTML is correct. There is no `&pound;`. And the website does have `meta="utf-8"` set up.

Comment: How would you send the `accept-charset` with the PHP client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**solution:**

Make sure the `mbstring` extension is enabled.

There was a [bug](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/4637) about failing tests with `iconv` reported in the kohana bugtracker.

---

**tips:**

As proposed in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573621/1832745) - you can test for correct UTF-8 output:

```
$this->assertEquals(
    mb_detect_encoding(
        crawler->filter("#error-notification")->text(),
        'UTF-8'
    ),
    'UTF-8'
);
```

---

You can include `accept-charset` headers with requests sent by the client:

```
$client->request(
    'POST', '/withdraw',
    array("amount" => 130),
    array(),
    array(),
    array('HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET' => 'utf-8')
);
```