# parse_url() behaving differently in PHPUnit and in plain PHP file

Tags: php, utf-8, phpunit

Debugging PHP code with UTF8 and IDN domains, I came to a discrepancy between a plain PHP file and a unit test I cannot explain, which boils down to how `parse_url()` works:

I have a test file with this:

```php
$url  = 'http://普遍接受-测试.世界';
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
var_dump('普遍接受-测试.世界' === $host);
```

This outputs `true`, as [expected](https://3v4l.org/f4tQH)

However, the same comparison fails in a unit test on the same PHP setup:

```php
class Test extends TestCase
{
    public function testParse()
    {
        $url = 'http://普遍接受-测试.世界';
        $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        $this->assertEquals( '普遍接受-测试.世界', $host );
    }
}
```

```sh
$ php phpunit-9.1.phar test.php
PHPUnit 9.1.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 00:00.140, Memory: 12.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Test::testParse
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'普遍接受-测试.世界'
+'普▒__接▒_▒-测试.世界'

D:\phpunit\test.php:31

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

So, it seems PHPUnit modifies the way PHP looks at UTF8 : any idea where I should look to fix this?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017744/testing-special-characters-with-php-unit which may work with the encoding.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help, `$this->assertEquals(mb_detect_encoding('普遍接', 'UTF-8'),'UTF-8' );`passes fine

Comment: I had to use UTF-8-aware custom function to parse UTF-8 path:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#114817